# Derive Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation with exponential term

Tags: optimization, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I want to find the $u$ that minimizes
\begin{align*}
E\left(\exp\left(\int_0^Tu_t\,dt + V_T^2\right)\right)
\end{align*}
given $dV_t = (\alpha V_t +u_t)\,dt + \sigma\,dW_t$.

Without the $\exp$ in the expectation, I would use the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation here with the optimal value function
\begin{align*}
 H(t,x) = \min_{u, V_t=x} E\left( \int_t^Tu_s^2\,ds + V_T^2 \, \vert\, \mathcal{F}_t \right),
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration generated by the Brownian motion $W_t$.
But when I start with
\begin{align*}
 H(t,x) = \min_{u, V_t=x} E\left(\exp\left( \int_t^Tu_s^2\,ds + V_T^2 \right)\, \vert\, \mathcal{F}_t \right),
\end{align*}
I get stuck at
\begin{align*}
 H(t,x) = \min_{u, V_t=x} E\left(\exp\left( \int_t^{t+h} u_s^2\,ds \right) H(t+h, V_{t+h}) \, \vert\, \mathcal{F}_t \right),
\end{align*}
Applying the Ito formula on $H(t+h, V_{t+h})$ gives me
\begin{align*}
H(t+h, V_{t+h}) = H(t, V_{t})
+ \int_t^{t+h} \frac{\partial H}{\partial s}
+ \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}(\alpha V_s+u_s)+\frac12 \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial x^2}\sigma^2 \,ds 
+ \int_t^{t+h} \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}\sigma\,dW_s
\end{align*}
and thus
\begin{align*}
E\left(H(t+h, V_{t+h})\,\vert\,\mathcal{F}_t\right) = H(t, V_{t})
+ E\left(\int_t^{t+h} \frac{\partial H}{\partial s}
+ \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}(\alpha V_s+u_s)+\frac12 \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial x^2}\sigma^2 \,ds\,\vert\,\mathcal{F}_t \right).
\end{align*}
Can some help me through the next steps to derive the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation for this problem?